# Working Java JNDI Lookup from EJB to WAR causes tons of log errors

Tags: java, ejb, war, jndi

I am using a lookup that looks like this:

```
package com.program.my.api;

import com.program.my.companies.CompanyManager; // Remote Interface in EJB

public class Services
{
    public static CompanyManager getCompanyManager() { return getService(CompanyManager.class); } 

    public static <T> T getService(Class<T> c)
    {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(System.getProperties());

            T result = (T) ctx.lookup(c.getName());

            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}

// Usage
@Stateless
@Path("/companies")
public class CompanyService
{
    @GET
    @Path("getCompanyOverview")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public CompanyOverviewTO getCompanyOverview(@QueryParam("id") int id)
    {
        return Services.getCompanyManager().getCompanyOverview(id);
    }
}
```

The lookup works! Ok, that's fine, but in the logs I get tons of errors that look like this:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:app/my-ejb-2.0/CompanyService!com.program.my.api.CompanyService
```

This doesn't make any sense. Mostly because the classname isn't in my api war, it's in the EJB, but also bc the code works. It just throws logs this error before it does.

It's needlessly filling up my logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: which server, which ejb version? is this a single ear, separtely deployed ejbs, ejb beans in a war, etc? be more specific as these scenarios may require different configurations

Comment: Glassfish. An EAR with one EJB and multiple WARS

Comment: Then why do a manual lookup? just use '@EJB' injection? But if you insist on manual lookup, i will post for you an answer to that.

Comment: Because @EJB results in the same error

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that packaging multiple WAR's into a single EAR was causing a lot of problems. Even though none of the url paths were crossing, Glassfish still didn't like it.

Merged everything into a single ear and all my problems disappeared.